# Why doesn't my jar file launch on double click?

Tags: java, program-entry-point

I'm having trouble launching a jar file on double click (and open with java SE ) ,the jar launches just fine from command line, other jars I have created launch fine from double click.

I exported the jar file using eclipse exporter ,I used the runnable jar export and and chose the right main() class under the run configuration

When I run the jar using `java -jar myjar.jar` it runs as expected no exceptions are thrown

I am under linux/windows both have the same problem I don't really see the point because other jar files I created using the same way run without any problem.

> Just for fun I created a `c` program containing only

```
int main(void){
   system("java -jar myjar.jar");
   return 0;
}
```

> When I double clicked the compiled `c` program my jar opened up !

Here is the MANIFEST

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: . libs/commons-compress-1.10.jar libs/zip4j_1.3.2.jar libs/xz.jar libs/commons-io-2.4.jar libs/oat2dex.jar
Main-Class: deodex.Tester
```

Here is the `main` method :
http://pastebin.com/M8Fhb4qW

```
package deodex;
import deodex.tools.Logger;
import deodex.ui.LangFrame;
import deodex.ui.Window;
public class Tester {
        public static void main(String args[]) {

        if (Cfg.isFirstLaunch()) {
                    Cfg.setCurrentLang(S.ENGLISH);
                    R.initResources();
                    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                    LangFrame win = new LangFrame();


        } else {
            Cfg.readCfg();
            R.initResources();
            S.initTempFolders();
            Logger.logToStdIO("[test]" + Cfg.getCurrentLang());

                    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                    Window win = new Window();



        }

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

**More details**
I tried adding a new `JFrame` before my code and the double click works just for that `JFrame`  that shows up and then it hangs there the other Windows that should launch just after that doesn't show up ,please tell me where to look ... why it does not work ? because it looks like my Classes that extends `JFram` needs terminal/cmd to show up ,I should also note that I am using a class called `R` to load the Strings from a text file depending on the Language and `Cfg` Class to check if the program first launched or has launched before and then load the proper language files and resources.

**Edit**
as suggested in the answer I removed all my JDK's and installed Oracle's JDk as described still have the same problem

Comment: explain how you created the .jar .... there are two types of .jar exec and non-exec

Comment: What happens / does not happen when you double click ? Which operating system are you talking about ? Linux ? Mac ? Windows ? Atari ? AmigaOS ?

Comment: Please do not use an external link for your code.  Include the code in your question.

Comment: @SrinathGanesh I updated the question ,I used eclipse export runnable jar didn't work and I tried export jar file still didn't work

Comment: @Marged I am using linux and windows it failed on both of them ,when launch from theminal jar runs as expected no exceptions are thrown

Comment: @VGR Thanks man ,I will take  note of that forgive my ignorance of the rules

Comment: Do you use the same jvm from the command line and when you double click?

Comment: @matt yes it's 8 on both ends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved My own problem here is why :
as I said in the details I use text resources from outside the `JAR` file and I used hard code to get those resources like `final File("lang/en.prop");`the thing is when launching from the `GUI` with open with JAVA SE ,it is like running a command to my jar from an other directory which will fail because the `Cfg`  class will throw a NullPointerException because the text resources are not there so I made a new Class called it PathUtils like this
**PathUtils.java**

```
    public static String getExcutionPath(){
        String path = "";
        try {
            path =PathUtils.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath();
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Somthing went wrong couldn't detemine our current location !");
        }
        return path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf("/"));
    }
```

now at the Launch I will first find my location on the file system and then set the values of the needed files for my program based on my current locations and now double click works like a charm ! simple

Answer (score -1):

The problem may live within improper installations of the Java SE Runtime Environment. It may be required to uninstall all traces of Java from your computer and re-install Java using an offline installer from the [Oracle Technology Network](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html).

On Linux, add the PPA `ppa:webupd8team/java` and install `oracle-java8-installer` - To my knowledge, it integrates with a lot of desktop environments, at least it does with Ubuntu Unity and XFCE, so double-clicking should work there too.

Comment: as I said in my question this is definitely not a file association problem

Comment: @lord-ralf-adolf Before you just say "it does not work" - have you tried the solution? It would be very frustrating seeking for a solution and possibly later finding out that this is indeed the correct solution

Comment: I already have OPENJDK8 , 7 and 6 and Oracle JDK 8 I don't see the point of reinstalling it just because one jar file out of thousands  on my pc doesn't work on double click or on right click open with JAVA 8 runtime ,please if you think this could help me explain me why ? my question is clear "WHY"

Comment: This is **the exact reason** why I was suspecting this: Multiple parallel java versions being installed causing a mess. Please, follow my advice, and report back. Uninstall everything and make a fresh install. It really does not help anybody if you don't cooperate.

Comment: ok ,I will cooperate sorry ,I just lost faith I will try that and post the results